# Cannot include path on Windows

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have tried adding include path to the bottom of the `.pro` file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Users\Alexandre\Desktop\meshlab-2016.12\vcglib-1.0.1"
```

Then I ran the qmake.

But I still have the errors:

```
C:\Users\Alexandre\Desktop\meshlab-2016.12\src\common\filterparameter.cpp:28: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'vcg/math/matrix44.h': No such file or directory
```

And many others similar to this.

Code looks like this:

```
#include <vcg/math/matrix44.h>
```

I have also tried changing the path to relative, using normal slashes and double backslashes.

Comment: I used this before try it: `INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../Projects/qmenu`

Comment: try INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\Users\\Alexandre\\Desktop\\meshlab-2016.12\\vcglib-1.0.1" or INCLUDEPATH += "/c/Users/Alexandre/Desktop/meshlab-2016.12/vcglib-1.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your project directory but if your directory is like this

```
projectFolder/vcg/math/matrix44.h
```

you can add header file path like this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/vcg/math
```

Then include header file without path:

```
#include <matrix44.h>
```

Also use $PWD to refer to the current project directory.

More info about PWD:

[The PWD variable specifies the full path leading to the directory containing the current file being parsed. This can be useful to refer to files within the source tree when writing project files to support shadow builds.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#pwd)